# Excel VBA NOW() pasted into cell not being recognised as date/time

Tags: excel, vba, userform

Im having trouble with the NOW() function after it is pasted into a cell.

To give you a brief description, I have built a Checkin window that records times of when people start end work via a user form for my event. Within the user form I display NOW() in a textbox then take that value and paste it into a "Records" tab which just records all checkins.

Here is the code in the user form- 
    `UserForm1.TextBox3.Value = Format(Now(), "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss")`

However the problems starts when I try and compare the NOW() paste result which looks like - 26/09/2018 14:30 as expected via `ActiveCell = TextBox3.Value` and formatted to short date, though when I try and compare to see if the result is equal to day 1 of my event which I have hand typed 26/09/2018 . It seems to not recognising the NOW() result as date/time. I have tried forcing it via datevalue() and changing it to text() but nothing Ive tried seems to work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Sorry in advanced Im a bit new to VBA but just discovering how powerful it can be.
David

Comment: What is appearing in the sheet?

Comment: So value that is pasted to the sheet is '26/09/2018 14:30' however when I try and format the cell to just show date via short date it stays as '26/09/2018 14:30'

Comment: If you just want the date in the cell, why not use `Today()`? `Now()` will tag time as well

Comment: By using `Format`, it's no longer date/time. Instead of pasting *text-that-looks-like-a-date*, set the cell's value equal to `Now` and format as needed.

Comment: Thanks for replying. After removing the format so my code now looks like 'UserForm1.TextBox3.Value = Now()'. The good new excel can now read the date/time of the paste and I can format it within the sheet however when I try an if statement comparing cell a1 (The cell with the pasted NOW() value and formatted to shortdate at sheet level) to a2 my hand written version of the same result is still results is a false. '=if(a1=a2,"Yes","No")' value in cell a1 = 28/09/2018 value in cell a2= 28/09/2018.

Comment: @Zac Thanks for replying as well. Unfortunately I would also like to store the time but I have that pasting in another cell since its to monitor what time people arrive for work and to check if its day 1 of the event or day 2.

Comment: not sure what you're doing exactly, but if you're writing a textbox' value into a cell, know that the textbox contains a `String` and you should use `CDate()` to convert that string into an actual `Date` value that Excel will definitely recognize as such. Treat dates as dates as soon as you possibly can - don't carry string-as-dates values around, work with `Date` values.

Comment: @Mathieu thanks, Unfortunately Im trying to have one value to carry through thats why I though of NOW() but thinking of the textbox could you suggest away that I could display the NOW() value without a textbox within the userform?

Comment: You can ***display*** it in the text box, but nothing says that you have to ***store*** it in the text box as a string.  Just put it in a form level variable and use that for your comparison.

Comment: @Comintern Good recommendation I didn't think of that, so now when the user enters the user form it **displays** the NOW() but dosn't actually store it in the textbox. When the user closes the userform I'm using 'ActiveCell = NOW()' to write it to my active cell while this does seem to work when I try and compare it again results in a false answer does cell a1 (with NOW() value) to a2 my hand written version of the same result is still results is a false. '=if(a1=a2,"Yes","No")' value in cell a1 = 28/09/18 value in cell a2= 28/09/18 both cells formatted in the worksheet as short date.

Comment: Value equality doesn't care for the text representation. If the underlying value of one cell is `28/09/18 1:49:27 PM` and the underlying value of the other cell is `28/09/18 1:49:32 PM` then the two values are not the same, regarldess of the text representation of the cells. If you don't care for the time portion, drop the decimals before doing the comparison.

Comment: @Mathieu Great explanation after formatting at sheet level to general I can see indeed that the values are different 43371.778 vs 43371.000 and after following your idea and using the trunc() function I think this might have solved my issue with the date by removing the decimal point without rounding up, and using a1-trunc(a2) to isolate the time without having the date. It definitely deserves an air fist bump!